# Power BI - Doubts

Tags: powerbi

I wanted to see the Item Level or Granular level data. I know that it can be seen using the drill-through functionality and have tried it. However, I wanted to know whether there is a way I can get it done using  **Only 1 click**. Can it be done?

Comment: Show your sample data and expected output.

Comment: You can use Bookmark

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just pull the data at the level you want.